# Is it a good idea to keep my nginx configuration on a github (private) repository?

Tags: git, nginx

Everything is in the title. I have access to slow servers, and I would like to keep track of server configuration changes, change the configuration locally and deploy changes easily.

My main concerns are security, since a server configuration would usually be accessible only to people who have access to the server.

Comment: Keep your Nginx configuration in a separate repo, then, which also contains other server configuration files, and only give access to people who need it. See how Ansible/Chef/Puppet manage server configuration.

Comment: Your server configuration is only as secure as you make github.

Answer (score -5):

nginx configuration is a very secured why you want to expose the configuration to everybody in team.
I mean to say there are chances by mistakenly team members can change the configuration.

I would suggest don't keep in github private repo